# What is the formal definition of an unqualified identifier in Java?

Tags: java, generics, identifier, jls

In Java, what is the formal definition of an "unqualified identifier"?

The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/jls17.pdf) mentions an unqualified identifier while defining what a type variable is, in section 4.4:

> A type variable is an unqualified identifier used as a type in class,
> interface, method, and constructor bodies.

However, I could not find any formal definition for unqualified (or qualified) identifier in the specification.

Is this available somewhere else in the documentation? Or is it considered too trivial to warrant a formal definition?

Note: The specification does define one other unqualified entity - the unqualified directive - in section 7.7.2:

> If an exports or opens directive has a to clause, then the directive
> is qualified; otherwise, it is unqualified.

Comment: It's a good question. [Section 6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.2) defines 'qualified names' as (my paraphrase) a dot-separated list of identifiers, so it would seem that in that context, identifiers are not themselves 'qualified'.  Which is backed up by [section 3.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8).   I used JLS 11 for reference.  Although a type variable does not seem to be a 'name', I still find no evidence of qualified identifiers elsewhere.

Comment: Thus 'unqualified identifier' is at best a redundancy.

Comment: [Section 6.5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.6.2) also refers to qualified expressions.  Hence, "qualified" has a common meaning in the JLS ... even if they don't explicitly define it.

Comment: Thanks passer-by and Stephen C. In the specification, the term qualified means different things in different sections/contexts, hence the ambiguity. Here, the context is type variables in generics.

Comment: See also [6.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.7). I think it's just saying that you can't qualify a type variable with a package or class name, e.g. `com.example.Foo.T`.

Comment: shmosel: Thanks. Probably I am being pedantic, but Section 6.7 discusses names, not identifiers. In addition, it doesn't discuss type variables in any way, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

We can go at this the other way. The quoted sentence just summarizes what a type variable is. The grammar has the formal definition of a *type variable*, from which we can deduce that an "unqualified" identifier is basically... an identifier.

*(from JLS 17):*

```
TypeVariable
    {Annotation} TypeIdentifier

TypeIdentifier:
    Identifier but not permits, record, sealed, var, or yield

Identifier:
    IdentifierChars but not a Keyword or BooleanLiteral or NullLiteral
```